# How do I change my account email?

Tags: origin, need-for-speed-most-wanted-2012

I am playing Need For Speed: Most Wanted 2012 on my PS3.

However, I want to change the account to which the PS3 is linked.

When I try to do this from Settings ---> Account Management ---> Account Management, I get a error. (You must be signed in to PlayStationNetwork and the EA servers in order to access the online features of this title.)

Howvever, I AM connected to PSN and the EA servers. (Atleast, I think I am, cause I can see that I'm connected to PSN in the XMB menu and I can play multiplayer, which means that I must be connected to the EA servers.

How do I change my account and can someone clarify this error?

**EDIT:** I am NOT reluctant to delete my game data or save data. (I haven't made it far into the game)